# Get value from KVO - returning NSConreteValue

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

I have the following KVO observer:

```
 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if context == &kvoContext {
            if (keyPath == "transform") {
                if let transform = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
                    print("transform: \(transform)")
                    overlay.transform = transform as! CGAffineTransform
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which prints out:

```
transform: CGAffineTransform: {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}}
```

However, in my variable window I see `transform` as an NSConcreteValue:

[image]

And I crash on that last line trying to set `overlay.transform`:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How do I retrieve that value?

Answer (score 1):

Your transform is being automatically boxed into an `NSValue` object. You'll need to access it like

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
  if context == &kvoContext {
    if (keyPath == "transform") {
      if let transform = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? NSValue {
        overlay.transform = transform.CGAffineTransformValue()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the same crash and I get `transform` as `null` now - http://imgur.com/dDdqRGx

Comment: Can you confirm your full code looks like the above. If this still crashes can you provide more information about the crash and an example of how you are registering and triggering this KVO. Also as a sidenote you want to be careful as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html) state `...UIKit framework generally do not support KVO...`