# Q:How to get CGPoint from NSConcreteValue?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I use RAC in my project to observe `tableView's` contentOffset, but I don't know how to extract the `x`, because the `id`'s type is `NSConcreteValue`:

```
[RACObserve(_tableview, contentOffset)
        subscribeNext:^(id  x){

            float currentOffsetY = x.y; // this line is wrong code.

     }];
```

I have referenced related questions:
[Get value from KVO - returning NSConreteValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686618/get-value-from-kvo-returning-nsconretevalue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [pointValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSValue/pointValue) property on `NSValue`. So you just need to cast the x parameter to `NSValue` because `NSConcreteValue` is a subclass of `NSValue`. Then you can extract the desired value from the `CGPoint` struct.

**Background information**

If you want to treat a C struct (e.g. `CGPoint` or `CGRect`) as an Objective-C Object, e.g., to add it to an `NSArray`, you need to wrap it in an object. Therefore, Apple has provided special initializers and getter on `NSValue`.

Comment: You mean :`CGPoint point = [(NSValue *)x pointValue];` ?but this is no use, it will report error.

Comment: the correct way of whiting is this: `CGPoint point = [(NSValue *)x CGPointValue]`; Thanks for your answer,cheers.